# vue way of .each()

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a hard coded menu.vue file that basically gets the url slug and adds a class of active if it matches the `<a>` href. It works just fine but I am sure there is a cleaner way of doing it so I am not copy/pasting the same code over and over. In Jquery I know I could just loop through all the `<a>` in an `each` and see if slug matches the href and `addClass`

menu.vue

```
<template>

  <div>

    <!-- Main site menu -->
    <nav>

     <ul>

       <a href="/about" v-bind:class="{'active' : slug == 'about'}"><li>about</li></a>
       <a href="/faq" v-bind:class="{'active' : slug == 'faq'}"><li>faq</li></a>
       <a href="/signup" v-bind:class="{'active' : slug == 'signup'}"><li>signup</li></a>
       <a href="/login" v-bind:class="{'active' : slug == 'login'}"><li>login</li></a>
       <a href="/contact" v-bind:class="{'active' : slug == 'contact'}"><li>Contact</li></a>

     </ul>

    </nav>

  </div>

</template>

<script>
    export default {    
        data(){
          return {
            slug: ''
          }
        },

        created(){
          var urlArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
          this.slug    = urlArray[1];
        },

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Put an array of `links` in your `data` object, and use `v-for` to step through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/46/

```
<div id="app">
 <p v-for="link in links" :key="link">
  <a :href="'/'+link" :class="{'active': slug == link}">{{link}}</a>
 </p>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    links: [
      'about',
      'home',
      'faq'
    ]
  }
});
```

In this example each link has a corresponding class, e.g. 'home' class, 'faq' class.

Comment: Add `:class="{'active': slug == link}"` and you're there based on his code.

Comment: Perfect! Actually works better like this so I can switch out the nav based on if a user is signed in or not.

Comment: Why? He wants one link that is active based on a condition.

Comment: @BertEvans you're right, I've missed this clue. Thanks.